# getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag returns different instance after rotate

Tags: java, android

I know if I rotate my device, the current activity gets destroyed and recreated. If a `savedInstanceState` is available in the activity`s onCreate(), I can avoid creating a new Fragment by calling

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        iMyFragment = new MyFragment()
        Log.d(TAG, "____ onCreate: iMyFragment: " + iMyFragment);
    } else {
        iLottoTicketFragment = (LottoTicketFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(MyFragment.FRAGMENT_TAG);
        Log.d(TAG, "____ savedinstance: iMyFragment: " + iLottoTicketFragment);
        if(iMyFragment == null) {
            iMyFragment = new MyFragment();
            Log.d(TAG, "____ recreate: iMyFragment: " + iLottoTicketFragment);
        }
    }
}
```

however the instance returned by `findFragmentByTag` is a different instance than before, causing all kind of trouble.

This is the log ouput (compare the ids 973eb65 and 73e27ce)

```
06-01 15:47:16.687 15729-15729/D/MainActivity: ____ onCreate: iMyFragment: MyFragment{973eb65}
06-01 15:47:29.774 15729-15729/D/MainActivity: ____ savedinstance: iMyFragment: MyFragment{73e27ce #1 id=0x7f0f0098 MyFragment}
```

Anyone knows how to get the exact same instance from `findFragmentById()`?

Comment: `setRetainInstance` ... as long as `Fragment` doesn't contains UI ... if it does you shouldn't use `setRetainInstance` and use this recreated one

Comment: The fragment contains UI. `setRetainInstance` indeed solves the problem, but it seems ugly. The problem with the recreated one is that it is not attached to activity cause trouble.

Comment: I think that you should accept the fact that the Fragment is re-created and fix the code around this. While it is possible to retain Fragments, I have never seen a valid use case for such a design.

Comment: any ideas how to attach the recreated fragment to the activity?

Comment: @Vasiliy I agree with the first part ... but retaining Fragments is very usefull ... [check the CacheFragment](http://selvin.pl/MainActivity.java.txt) ... on rotation Activity is recrated but data stays in cache fragment which is retained ... it avoid netwar calls on rotation/configuration change

Comment: @Selvin, IMHO this is one of the worst patterns in Android development. It got extended by introduction of `ViewModel` arch component, which made me write this post: https://www.techyourchance.com/android-viewmodel-architecture-component-dangerous/

Comment: ViewModel.... Which is not even in beta... This is the right pattern as it was stated on Google io when ViewModel was introduced(as old way) ... Evolution was Activity. setRetainInstance, retainable Fragment, ViewModel....  And since ViewModel is not released jet it is a right patty

Comment: @dan, define `FrameLayout` inside the `Activity` and then just add the newly created `Fragment` dynamically. Details here: http://coreylatislaw.com/managing-static-and-dynamic-fragments/

Answer (score 0):

When the device is rotated a new activity is created. The state is preserved but all the views and fragments are recreated.